# Getting the distribution function from this density function

Tags: probability, analysis

I got the following density function:

$$\begin{cases}
 4e^{-4(x-1)} & \mbox{if} \; x \ge 1 \\
 0 & \mbox{if}\; x \lt 1
\end{cases} $$

Now I want to get the distribution function which I thought is

$$ \int 4e^{-4(x-1)} = -e^{-4(x-1)} $$

But I think this distribution function is wrong and I don`t know what I am missing.
Thanks for any answer and comment in advance.

Comment: This distribution function is $F(x) = \int_1^x e^{-4(x-1)} dx$, not the indefinite integral.

Comment: Should the upper bound be infinity?

Comment: You only "think" that $-e^{-4(x-1)}$ is not a distribution function instead of _knowing_ that the function cannot possibly be a distribution function (whose value is a probability and hence is nonnegative)?